# What to do without required knowledge?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

I am really new to review. I now found this suggested edit:

> https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6047954

where an accepted answer from twenty months ago, with +120, got corrected as "does not compile".

Although I don't have the skills to verify this personally, I can only believe that this edit, although it may be correct now and in the SDK version used by the editor, clearly was not correct twenty months ago. Still, it may improve the post for the future; but I just can't tell.

What should I do in such border cases: Skip or Reject?

Comment: There is no shame in skipping. (OMG! I was typing this while gnat was submitting his link.)

Comment: @Louis I AM skipping most of the queue, for some reason or another. But in this case, gut feeling tells me that this edit is wrong, and can have unintended consequences, if it should be accepted. The duplicate  is "Skip or accept", not "Skip or reject", by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very clear that the author's intent is for that code to be there.  They didn't *accidentally* add that whole line of code.   If it's wrong then the correct course of action is to downvote the post and optionally comment, not remove the code.  Where the problem to appeared to have been a likely mistake to which the authors intentions to have been the correct working code, then an edit to fix it would have been appropriate.

Answer (score 5):

Skip it.

Leave it for someone who has the skills to verify whether it's technically correct or not.

Comment: Let this not be confused with VTD flags on answers; voting to delete should *not* be used to judge the *technical* accuracy of answers.